# KeyError: 'browser' with Splinter and Behaving automated testing

Tags: python, automated-tests, splinter, python-behave

I followed the instructions here: http://shon.github.io/2014/06/19/ui_testing_and_bdd.html  about setting up Splinter with Behaving to run automated tests. I'm able to run a test successfully, but at the end of the test, it throws an error saying:

KeyError: 'browser'

and it won't continue testing any additional feature files. I'm pretty new to python and need some help in troubleshooting this.

```
Exception KeyError: 'browser'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/behave", line 11, in <module> sys.exit(main())
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/behave/__main__.py", line 109, in main
failed = runner.run()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 672, in run
return self.run_with_paths()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 693, in run_with_paths
return self.run_model()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 483, in run_model
failed = feature.run(self)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/behave/model.py", line 523, in run
failed = scenario.run(runner)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/behave/model.py", line 867, in run
runner.run_hook('before_scenario', runner.context, self)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 405, in run_hook
self.hooks[name](context, *args)
File "features/environment.py", line 48, in before_scenario
context.browser = default_browser
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/behave/runner.py", line 223, in __setattr__
record = self._record[attr]
KeyError: 'browser'
```

Comment: could you please post full traceback

Comment: @AndreyRusanov edited post to include traceback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. It is related to the Feature file structure. The Feature file was missing:

```
 Background:
    Given a browser
```

This also required changes to the environment.py file based on the info here: https://github.com/ggozad/behaving